# React js - does the componentDidMount() code sent to client browser as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and am learning by doing.. will the 
code in componentDidMountt() be sent to client browser just like other JavaScript in html files? I am concerned as I will be calling fetch with url for api in the componentDidMount(). Or the code all stays in server and only what changes between virtual Dom and real Dom is being transferred to the client browser without any js whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, yes, all of your React components (including their code) would be sent to the client (browser), though technically React isn't involved in that part of the setup.

You generally don't want to send any secrets to the client, instead relying on backend code that you control to access secrets and make the necessary calls to third-party APIs. With serverless setups like AWS Lambda you don't even need to run a server to make this work.

Comment: I understand the first part of the answer. But I tried to save the page in browser as webpage complete. There was a minified Js which was mostly unreadable. I did text search for the url in fetch but could not locate it. Don't understand that part. Do you think I missed something? To understand the second part, I will read about aws lambda. When you say I should handle fetch in backend... Something like java and not in reactjs at all?

Answer (score 0):

It can actually can... for example in this code when component gets mounted in fetches data from youtube....

```js
class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: [],
      currentVideo: null
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchYouTube('learn javascript');
  }
  
  fetchYouTube (query) {
    let options = {
      query: query,
      key: YOUTUBE_API_KEY
    };
    this.props.searchYouTube(options, (videos) => {
      this.setState({
        videos: videos, 
        currentVideo: videos[0]
      });
    });
  }
  
  handleVideoClick (video) {
    this.setState({
      currentVideo: video
    });
  } 
  
  render () { 
    return (
    <div>
      <Nav handleSearchChange={_.debounce((input) => this.fetchYouTube(input), 500)} />
      <div className="col-md-7">
        <VideoPlayer video={ this.state.currentVideo } />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-5">
        <VideoList videos={ this.state.videos } listClick={this.handleVideoClick.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

// In the ES6 spec, files are "modules" and do not share a top-level scope
// `var` declarations will only exist globally where explicitly defined
window.App = App;
```